# Flask templating structure

Tags: templates, flask

This is the my folder structure.

```
 templates
 -auth
 --login.html
 -includes
 --header.html
-layouts
--layout_login.html
```

Currently I have created skeleton like this.
layout_login.html has skeleton of login page. within that I have included header.html

login.html, I have extended layout_login.html but its not rendering, jinja is not able to find the layout_login.html

Pls advice, what's m missing.

```
{% include 'includes\header.html' %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought to delete the Question but then it may helps someone who do same mistake like I did.

Use

```
    {% include 'includes/header.html' %}
```

Instead

```
    {% include 'includes\header.html' %}
```